# Fourier series of $f(x) = x - [x]$, where $[x] = n \in Z$ s.t. $n \leq x < n+1$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

How do you find the Fourier series of $f(x) = x - [x]$, where $[x] = n \in Z$ s.t. $n \leq x < n+1$?

I am familiar with Fourier series and use the following definition to solve them:

$f(x) = \displaystyle\frac{a_{0}}{2} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_{n}\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right) + b_{n}\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$ where the interval is $[-L,L]$.

$a_{0} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)dx$

$a_{n} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx$

$b_{n} = \displaystyle\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)\sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx$

In a similar manner, if the interval was from $[0,2L]$ the integrals would just run from $0$ to $2L$.

I am unsure how to set up my $a_{0}$, $a_{n}$, and $b_{n}$ for this specific question. I do not want the answer to the Fourier series. I can do that on my own. I just want to know what my $a_{0},a_{n},b_{n}$ would look like in terms of the way I defined them above.

Comment: You must take $L=1$, and you can simplify matters if you integrate in $[0,1]$.

Comment: $2L$ denotes the periodicity of your Fourier series, and should match that of your function. So, what's the period of your function? (FYI, your $[x]$ is more typically denoted as the floor function $\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Comment: Well the floor function as you mentioned seems to always have period 1. However correct me if I am wrong but if I have period $1$ then when looking at cosine and sine defined in the formulas for $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ there should be a $2n\pi x$ in the numerator instead of a $n\pi x$? Also, what would my $f(x)$ be then in the formulas? I defined $f(x) = x - [x]$ but how do you integrate the floor function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $$f(x):=x-\lfloor x\rfloor={\rm fractional\ part\ of}\ x$$  is periodic with period $1$; whence $L={1\over2}$ in your notation. Furthermore it is allowed (also by you) to take the interval $[0,2L]$ as fundamental interval instead of $[{-L},L]$. But in the interval $[0,2L[=[0,1[\ $ the function $f$  is  given by
$$f(x)=x\qquad(0\leq x<1)\ .\tag{1}$$
Therefore you can just plug  $(1)$ into your formulas, with integration running over $[0,1]$.

An inspection of the graph of $f$ shows that $x\mapsto f(x)-{1\over2}$ is an odd function. Therefore you will obtain $a_0=1$, and all $a_n$ with $n\geq1$ are zero.